# Worst way to solve Rubik's in one algorithm

Tags: rubiks-cube, algorithm, twisty-puzzles

If you apply the same algorithm over and over again the cube will be solved.
I want to know what algorithm is the worst one (the one with the longest cycle)
I have found RU (cycle of 60 times)
I have found one of 72 but I can't remember it

Comment: Cycling RU solves the cube in 60 times? I didn’t know that was possible

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to find

> An element of the Rubik's cube group whose order is as large as possible.

One such example that satisfies this is

> $(RU^2D^{-1}BD^{-1})$ which has the maximum attainable order of $1260$

In particular,

> Starting from a solved cube, you need to apply this algorithm $1260$ times to get back to the beginning.

As mentioned by armb in the comments, there is a good answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3029900/314970) discussing the maximum orders for an $n \times n \times n$ Rubiks cube.

Comment: Can you prove that?

Comment: @pgp1 you can do it yourself - simply apply the algorithm 1260 times! :P

Comment: "apply the algorithm 1260 times" proves it has order 1260, it doesn't prove that that is the maximum possible order. For the latter, see  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2392906/determine-the-highest-order-of-an-element-of-a-rubiks-cube-group

Comment: @armb This is very useful, I may add this link to the answer.